# How to Save an array of Objects (just the fields) to a DB using DataTable?

Tags: c#, arrays, database, soap

I have a webservice (SOAP), from where I get an ArrayOfHumans (Array of Objects), I can get the array but I am having a hard time, saving it to the DB, something as simple (or maybe it is not so simple and I am just ignorant!) as taking an object from the array, and then getting the value of one property and saving that in a table column. I have the following code:

```
public JsonResult returnAllHumans()
{
    TestService.TestServiceSoapClient soapClient = new TestService.TestServiceSoapClient();
    object[] humansfromWS = soapClient.GetAllHumans();

    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));


    for (int i = 0; i < humansfromWS.Length; i++){
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    humansfromWS[i].Age(); (And my problem is here!)
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong to get this out of my array?, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: FYI, there are newer and more convenient methods than `DataTable` for reading and writing a database. You could use Entity Framework, for instance.

Comment: I know, but I am required to.

Comment: Surely you can find some examples of entering data into the database in other code in your project?

Comment: I am writing this from scratch, It is the first time I see this, I am more familiar with other Languages. I get the concept, I am having a hard time with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`humansfromWS[i]` is an object, it has no `Age` method. You have to cast it to the right type.

Comment: I have another question, How do I do that? could you give me an example?, when I compile it and inspect, I can see humansfromWS array, and see its objects, which have the properties Age, name, etc, I know it is not a method, it is a property.

Comment: What is the *type* of the elements in the array?

Comment: The type is Human? So cast to Human: `humansfromWS[i] as Human`

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the documentation on the [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.add.aspx) method. There are two versions of `Add`. One takes a `DataRow`, the other takes an array of values for a single row.

```
public JsonResult returnAllHumans()
{
    TestService.TestServiceSoapClient soapClient = new TestService.TestServiceSoapClient();
    object[] humansfromWS = soapClient.GetAllHumans();

    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));


    for (int i = 0; i < humansfromWS.Length; i++){
        var humanFromWS = humansfromWS[i];
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    humansFromWS.FirstName,
                    humansFromWS.LastName,
                    humansFromWS.Gender,
                    humanFromWS.Age});
    }
```

or

```
    for (int i = 0; i < humansfromWS.Length; i++){
        var humanFromWS = humansfromWS[i];
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row["Age"] = humanFromWS.Age;
        row["FirstName"] = humanFromWS.FirstName;
        row["LastName"] = humanFromWS.LastName;
        row["Gender"] = humanFromWS.Gender;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```